# How to make Facebook API calls from server? Which token to use?

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, mean-stack

Could someone please explain the process flow of Facebook API calls from the server side? I understand the general process, but I do not know HOW to do it.

I want my website server to use login credentials (either with `user access token` or `app access token`) to periodically send API calls... approx every 15 mins. The purpose of getting the data from the server side is so I can save this data to my own database. For example, the results of the following API call:

```
`GET/v2.5/2405794352058/feed      // get the latest posts from fb group feed`

// returns an array of objects
// [{message:'something interesting', id: '23435jlf8923', updated_at: Date()}]
```

In order to make these calls, I must use a `user access token` or `app access token`, which will exist for a finite amount of time before needing to re-login. If I opt to use a `user access token` I will be able to use a variety of tokens to get data and thus it is unlikely I will hit any usage limits. However, if I use an `app access token` I will have direct control of the access token, but all requests will originate with this same token. Which should I use?

I do not know how to do either of these techniques. The important thing I would like to know is HOW TO DO IT.

Here's what my server code currently looks like (returns 500 internal server error):

```
router.post('/check_posts', function(req, res, next){
    var accessToken = req.body.accessToken;
    var feed;

    FB.api("/142985255268/feed?limit=100",
        {access_token: accessToken},
        function (response) {
          if (response && !response.error) {
            console.log(response.data);
            feed = response.data;
            res.json(feed);
          }
        }
    );
});
```

I am using NodeJS, AngularJS, MongoDB and ExpressJS (aka Mean Stack).

Comment: Is group public(`fb group feed`)?

Comment: Yes it is a public feed

Comment: The id you are using is an feed id not page id?

Comment: I just used a random id for this Stack Overflow question. In reality I am using a Group ID

Comment: Use app access token in this format `appId|accSecret`;

Comment: So like {access_token: `4563dg3356 | 356dfg356`} ?

Comment: Let appId = `123456` & appSecret = `asdjhjasd` then app access token will be `12345|asdjhjasd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Tokens are valid forever. If you use the same User Token for the call, you may just use an App Token - because there are limits per Token. If you store User Tokens from other Users of your App, it´s better to use those - to avoid limits. Extended User Tokens are valid for 60 days.

More information:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

For using the Facebook API on your Node.js Server, either do your own calls or use one of the Third Party SDKs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apis-and-sdks#third-party-sdks

Comment: I have read that documentation but my server side API calls are not working. I have edited my question to show the code that I am using... hopefully it only needs a few tweaks?

Comment: how are you including FB? it looks like the javascript sdk, but that one only works on the client...

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know the javascript SDK ONLY works on client! So how do I calls from a NodeJS server?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apis-and-sdks#third-party-sdks

Comment: Ahh, i see. So facebook's default backend API runs on PHP and they open access to 3rd party SDKs. Thank you!

Comment: what? no. there is a difference between API and SDK. there is one graph api, but there are different SDKs in different languages to use the API, and you can also use HTTP requests without any SDK.